# Android - changing ringtone for incoming call before receiving it with class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener

Tags: android, telephonymanager, ringtone, phone-state-listener

i can change ringtone on incoming call with this code:

```
public class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        switch (state) {

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            {

                RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                        MyRingtoneURI );

             }
             break;
         }
    }
}
```

But the real issue is that sometimes the ringtone change process doesn't happen fast enough and i get my old ringtone and not this one. it happens because the phone starts to ring and doesn't wait for the code.

So my question is, can i change the ringtone before it gets to this code ? is there an option to delay the incoming call for a half a second so i can change the ringtone and then tell it to continue with the call ?

Comment: You can set priority of your receiver to max(9999), doing this would make your app to be the first to receive the incoming call intent fired by OS. 

When you are finished resetting the ring tone, only then other apps will get a chance to handle this intent.

However, I do not know if this would work on latest API level

Comment: thank you for your quick response!
that's a good idea! i'm doing it without the the receiver. i'm adding it to the manifest under my activity:
     <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                </intent-filter>
i ran a few calls it seems to work!! i will make a lot more calls and will update soon .

Comment: i meant <intent-filter android:priority="9999"> ...

after running a few calls most of them work but sometimes the code still getting missed and the ringtone stays default and doesn't change to the one i want... :(

Comment: @RonyEidlin Can you share solution for the same ? How you solved it ?

Comment: I didn't solve it yet i'm sorry... it's a side project that i sometimes try to work on.
i worked with Galaxy S1 and setting the priority didn't help...
so i'm thinking maybe it's the device . anyway when i have a solution i promise i will share it thanks :)